# How can I get most active 10% users in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I would like to perform some aggregations on the most active 10% users.

Lets say my doc is:

```
{
  "createDate": "2014-10-7T05:43:02",
  "user":"Raz",
  "os":"IOS"
},
{
  "createDate": "2014-10-7T07:43:02",
  "user":"Raz",
  "os":"Android"
},
{
  "createDate": "2014-10-7T09:43:02",
  "user":"Jim",
  "os":"Android"
}
```

and my aggregation is:

```
"aggs": {
"time_aggs": {
  "date_histogram": {
    "field": "createDate",
    "interval": "10m"
  },"aggs": {
     "device_os":{
        "term": {
            "os":"IOS"
         }
      }
    }
 }
```

What should I add in the aggregations to apply them only on the most 10% active users ?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you define an "active user"?

Comment: Someone who is in the event (represented by the document above) in a certain time period. For instance, in the example I provided, Raz is more active than Jim on october 7.

Comment: You may be able to use the percentiles aggregation for this and maybe combine it with a terms query on user. Not quite sure if this is possible though it might be possible using some scripting.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-percentile-aggregation.html

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm implementing this by calculating the number of distinct users in certain time range  (using cardinality aggregation). Then I aggregate the term clientId with size which reflect 10% from the distinct users.